# How to convert a date string in jquery to a desired format

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, date

I am getting a data string in jQuery in the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD`.
Now I want to show it like this: `24 Aug 2014`.
It can be done easily in php by using date function but do not know in jQuery.

```
$("#txt_birth_date").html(' ' + ((result.birth_date) === null) ? '' : result.birth_date));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use a library like this:
    https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat.

But if you want to format a string from `2014-08-24` into `24 Aug 2014`, you can wirte something like this:

```
function myFormatDate(d){
    var mothes   = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var d_y = d.split('-')[0];
    var d_m = d.split('-')[1];
    var d_d = d.split('-')[2];

    var mon = mothes[parseInt(d_m,10)-1];
    var dd = parseInt(d_d,10);

    if(d_y == "0000"){ // EDITED 
        return  dd + " " + mon;
    }else{
        return  dd + " " + mon + " " + d_y;
    }
}
var d = "2014-08-24";
alert(myFormatDate(d));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and if how to hide a date if it is set to '0000'?

Comment: @user3351494, Could you explain more about it? You want to hide a date which is shown on HTML ?

Comment: if '0000' comes in year then can we hide it and only show 15 aug.

Comment: @user3351494, I edited my code above. I hope this is what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Moment.js has great documentation.

http://momentjs.com

Comment: it is really a good thing.i also want to knoe that is there any other way to do this without using momentjs or Datejs?

Comment: I use moment.js and would recommend it to anyone dealing with dates in javascript- whether it be formatting dates, parsing dates or date computation.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Date formatting or date calculation in javascript is not as straight forward as in php. I'm using the [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library: